# generate table rows while foreach is in progress

Tags: php, foreach

Basically the title says it all.

I generate about 400 `<trs>` for a report and it takes about 30 seconds for the page to show any content(basically its  a blank page that is loading) and what I want is to see some data while the foreach generates the TRs

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: web php or cli php?

Comment: @CarlosZerga i dont know what y r talking about lmao

Comment: so i think its impossible, because when user download an html file, all php code declared in that file has been executed at backend side( all the 400 elements has been already printed before the user recieve the html file), and the progress bar is something for front-end side

Comment: 400 rows shouldn't take that long, for sure! Query optimization before all maybe ? beside that, if you can do this (not all the data needed at once), why not use pagination ?

Comment: Is the 400 rows the result of a query?  Maybe some cURL?  You will need to show your code so we can find ways to help you optimize

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

Basically `ob_start()` prevents output from being sent to the page automatically and instead is stored in an internal buffer which you can call the contents of by using `ob_get_contents()`.

So after each row is generated you can use `ob_get_contents()` and send the results then clean the buffer.  Check out the docs for more details.

Comment: Well ,I just put the next things right before the closing } for the foreach:  ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_flush();
  }  Did I do it wrong or ? It works pretty good tbh